# time.After not getting triggered after specified time

Tags: go, time

I am using **go1.10 darwin/amd64** and trying to set custom timeout for my testing during runtime using the following code snippet.

And I am executing the test using the command by setting Go's timeout to 11m and setting the test's panic timer to 5m and observed that Go timeout value is getting triggered and not mine.

```
go test github.com/foo -run TestMod -v --race -timeout 11m
...
...
*** Test killed with quit: ran too long (12m0s).
```

**Code snippet:**

```
// Returns time.Duration from given string
// Default return value: "2h0m0s"
func GetDuration(timeoutStr string) time.Duration {
    // Default timeout to 2 hours
    durationToReturn := (2 * time.Hour)

    pattern, _ := regexp.Compile("^([0-9]+)([mhd])$")

    // Calculates only if valid pattern exists
    if pattern.MatchString(timeoutStr) {
        match := pattern.FindStringSubmatch(timeoutStr)
        timeoutVal, err := strconv.Atoi(match[1])
        if err != nil {
            return durationToReturn
        }
        timeoutDuration := time.Duration(timeoutVal)
        switch match[2] {
        case "m":
            durationToReturn = timeoutDuration * time.Minute
        case "h":
            durationToReturn = timeoutDuration * time.Hour
        case "d":
            durationToReturn = timeoutDuration * (time.Hour * 24)
        }
    }
    return durationToReturn
}

// Starts timeout trigger based on given value in suiteData.Timeout
func StartTimeoutTimer() {
    timeoutStr := "5m"
    go func() {
        timeoutDuration := GetDuration(timeoutStr)
        fmt.Printf("Setting timeout of %v from %v\n", timeoutDuration, time.Now())
        <-time.After(timeoutDuration)
        fmt.Printf("Timeout happened at %v\n", time.Now())
        panic("Test timed out..")
    }()
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    StartTimeoutTimer()
    for {
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for {}` to block indefinitely. That's a busy loop that burns CPU and offers no opportunity for the scheduler to interrupt it. Use an empty select instead: `select {}`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. After adding the `select {}` statement, it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that the new goroutine in `StartTimeoutTimer()` will be executed. `StartTimeoutTimer()` return immediately after creating the new goroutine.

I think what you want is something like

```
done := make(chan struct{})
go func(){
    testFunc()
    close(done)
}()
select {
    case <- time.After(duration):
        panic("...")
    case <- done:
}
```

Comment: No I tried to move the go routine call to outer level. ie: `go StartTimeoutTimer()`. Even then the results are same